# Why does accepting an answer made by a user without an account on the site not award reputation?

Tags: bug, status-completed, accepted-answer, migrated-questions

I asked a few questions on Guitars.SE and they all got migrated to [Music & Performance](http://music.stackexchange.com). As is normal with migrations, accepted answers got cleared, so I went back to re-accept.

The two questions where the accepted answer was made by a user with an account on Music.SE awarded me +2 reputation for accepting the answer. The other two, however, were made by people who didn't have an account on Music and the answers are now orphaned. Accepting those did not award the reputation.

Is that right? It seems like the reward for accepting an answer should be independent of the answer author's status.

The questions that awarded rep correctly are [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1695/223) and [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1652/223). The ones that did not are [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1103/223) and [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1130/223).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were simply ahead of the times. (:

A fix for this was pushed out a day after you voted.  If you take a look at your reputation audit, you'll see the +2 entries as you'd expect.  If you do a recalc you'll get the +4.